# How to specify a filter with the PHP Solr client?

Tags: php, solr, facet, faceted-search

I'm using the PHP Solr client and I want to add a `fq` (Solr filter query) for this color value: `149,163,166`

```
$additionalParameters['facet']          = 'true';
$additionalParameters['facet.mincount'] = 0;
$additionalParameters['facet.limit']    = 25; // default = 100      
$additionalParameters['facet.field']    = array(
                                            'closest_rgb',
                                            'price'
                                          );
$additionalParameters['fq']             = '149,163,166';

$obj_results = $obj_solr->search($search_query, $int_offset, $int_limit, $additionalParameters);
```

Did I forget something? Because I don't any get results with the PHP client.

By calling this URL

```
select?q=soort_id:19&facet=true&facet.field=closest_rgb&fq=closest_rgb:149,163,166
```

there are results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the field name in the fq statement.

`$additionalParameters['fq'] = 'closest_rgb:149,163,166';`

Comment: Thank you and i've i have multiple fq like
$additionalParameters['fq'] = 'price:price:[100 TO 200]';
    $additionalParameters['fq'] = 'closest_rgb:'.$obj_request->closest_rgb.'';